# ¿En que afecta el rango de un tipo de dato especifico en lenguaje C?

Tags: c

En la mayoria de los videos de `C` muestran una tabla con el tipo de dato, su tamaño y el rango.

En el caso de los `INT` el valor esta entre `-32768 a 32767`.

Quisiera saber en que afecta esto, pues coloque un valor como este `33000` y se muestra normal, que representa ese `32767` y en su defecto los rangos en general

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pasa que realmente el rando de un `int` en algunas plataformas es ese: `-32768` a `32767` (plataformas de 16 bits). Pero en plataformas de 32 bits, el `int` es más grande. Probablemente tu estás en una plataforma moderna (de 32 ó 64 bits) por lo tanto tu `int` puede alojar un rango mucho más grande.

Con este código puedes saber el tamaño de un `int` en tu plataforma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("Tamaño del int: %d\n", sizeof(int));
  printf("INT_MAX: %d\n", INT_MAX);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: estoy usando CPPeditor en Android meti 9999999999 y me sale negativo, entonces ese valor corresponde a un numero y en el caso de los char una cantidad de caracteres?

Comment: La respuesta no es del todo correcta. Para mostrar un `size_t`, se usa `"%zu"`. Es lo indicado según el estándar.

Answer (score 5):

Bueno, los tipos integrales en C y en la mayoría de los lenguajes tienen algo llamado *limites*, puedes encontrar una cabecera en tu compilador de C llamada `limits.h` donde estan todos los limites en tu plataforma actual.

El tema con los limites, es el siguiente:

Un `int` son  32 bytes, ¿Correcto?
Un `long long` son 64 bytes.

Llevando esto al sistema hexadecimal puedes tener los siguientes valores:

```
FF FF FF FF <- Int
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF <- Long long.
```

Entonces, tienes desde  `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` hasta `FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF` en valores para un entero largo (long long).

¡Pero! Sucede que a la hora de realizar el tema de los signos en tipos integrales...

Cuando un número tiene signo, sólo tienes disponible la mitad de su rango real de valores, dado que se utilizan ciertos estándares para representar el signo, por ejemplo el siguiente programa:

```
int main(void) {
    int test = 0xFFFFFFF0;
    printf("%d - %u\n", test, (unsigned int)test);
}
```

Te dará como resultado:

```
-16 - 4294967280
```

Y si pruebas a invertir los bytes:

```
int main(void) {
    int test = 0x0000000f;
    printf("%d - %u\n", test, (unsigned int)test);
}
```

Vas a obtener el siguiente resultado:

```
15 - 15
```

Con todo esto, el tamaño de algunos tipos (en bytes), estos datos pueden variar dependiendo de la plataforma:

```
- char      : 1   <- Este es de tipo integral.
- short     : 2
- int       : 4
- float     : 4
- long      : 8 (64 bits)
- long long : 8
- double    : 8
```

Aquí debajo un programa que lo demuestra.

```
int main(void) {
    printf("sizeof(char)      == %d\n"
           "sizeof(short)     == %d\n"
           "sizeof(int)       == %d\n"
           "sizeof(float)     == %d\n"
           "sizeof(long)      == %d\n"
           "sizeof(long long) == %d\n"
           "sizeof(double)    == %d\n",
           sizeof(char), sizeof(short), sizeof(int),
           sizeof(long), sizeof(float), sizeof(long long), sizeof(double)
          );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Como referencia adicional, para conocer los límites actuales de un tipo dado puedes recurrir a la librería [limits.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/limits.h.html) (otro [enlace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/) de C++):

```
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Rango para int (%d,%d)\n",INT_MIN,INT_MAX);
  printf("Rango para unsigned int (%u,%u)\n",UINT_MIN,UINT_MAX);
}
```